# Database connectivity error in Visual FoxPro 9 application [DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv())

Tags: sql-server, odbc, visual-foxpro

I have a Visual FoxPro 9 application which loads a large amount of data from text files into a small number of tables in a SQL Server database.  The VFP9 application is not running on the same machine as the SQL Server.

I can not reproduce the error on demand, and it is sporadic; we will sometimes go for weeks without seeing it, and then we will see it two or three times in one week.

The initial error message in my application's log file is:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv())
```

...after which, any attempt to write the DB generates this error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure
```

I am not a FoxPro develoepr and this is a legacy application without a great deal of support.  If anyone else has encountered this, I would be very grateful for detailed explanations of solutions that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally as it says, a communication failure.  Something happened to break the connection, or possibly one side is taking too long to respond and a timeout occurs.  We've seen this happen a few times over the years and never found a satisfactory answer, but I've always suspected that either the client or server machine got very busy, causing the timeout - stuff like a full virus scan starting, perhaps.